# I got an error #1064 during saving files ,data into my sqli database?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Im trying to creat a database for storing Photos in my sqli with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE `photos`.`images` ( 
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `file` BLOB BINARY NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

so when i try to save it i got the following error . The error is the this :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BINARY NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 1

does someone whats the error about !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `BINARY` keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE `photos.images` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `file` BLOB NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: so binary doesn't matter if you store the image as BLOB ?

Comment: "A BLOB is a binary large object that can hold a variable amount of data." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html

Comment: @burimrexhepi `CHAR` and `TEXT` have `CHARACTER SET` such as `BINARY`.  `BLOB` has no variants.

Comment: i goth that now i was reading about Binary and BLOB ; Thank you Rick  a lot for the help!